# How to change the search action in wordpress search bar?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search

Create a new post and publish it.

The title is `my test for search`, content in it is as below:

```
no host route
```

Check what happen in wordpress database.

```
 select post_title from wp_posts
     where post_content like "%no%"
       and post_content like "%route%"
       and post_content like "%to%"
       and post_content like "%host%";
```

The post named `my test for search` will not be in the select's result.
Type `no route to host` in wordpress search bar,and click enter.
The post named `my test for search` shown as result.

[image]

I found the reason that the webpage contain `to` ,in the left upper side corner ,there is a word `Customize` which contains the searched word `to`.
How to change such search action in wordpress serach bar?
I want to make the search behavior in wordpress saerch bar, for example ,when you type `no route to host`, equal to the following sql command.

```
select post_title from wp_posts where post_content like "%no%route%to%host%";
```

All the plugins in my wordpress.

```
CodePen Embedded Pens Shortcode
Crayon Syntax Highlighter
Disable Google Fonts
Quotmarks Replacer
SyntaxHighlighter Evolved
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_posts`.  I am suspicious of the collation.

Comment: Your search query is not the one generated by a default WP install. Looks like you've modified it. The search supports GET parameters like sentence and exact, but they will not generate your wanted `post_content like "%no%route%to%host%";`. Can you expand furher why Customize label is affecting your search, it should be totally unrelated to the search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's *this* addition to the SQL WHERE clause on [`wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:1306`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1343):

```
<?php
// wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:~1306

foreach ( $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
    //...
    $like = $n . $wpdb->esc_like( $term ) . $n;
    $search .= $wpdb->prepare( "{$searchand}(({$wpdb->posts}.post_title $like_op %s) $andor_op ({$wpdb->posts}.post_excerpt $like_op %s) $andor_op ({$wpdb->posts}.post_content $like_op %s))", $like, $like, $like );
    // ...
```

Therefore, I'd hook into the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), and supply the words of the query as explicit "`search_terms`", since they get added into that clause, with the `LIKE` modifier just as you said were looking for!

So, we might do something like this:

```
<?php
// functions.php

function fuzzify_query(\WP_Query $q) {
    if (true === $q->is_search()
        && true === property_exists($q, 'query')
        && true === key_exists('s', $q->query)
    ) {
        $original_query = $q->query['s'];
        $words          = explode(' ', $original_query);
        $fuzzy_words    = array_map(
            function($word) {
                return '%'.$word.'%';
            },
            $words
        );

        $q->query_vars['search_terms'] = $fuzzy_words;

        return $q;
    }

    return $q;
}

 add_action('pre_get_posts', 'fuzzify_query', 100); // Or whatever priority your fuzziness requires!
```

Comment: This will not generate `like "%no%route%to%host%"` as wanted by OP. Sounds more like you're trying to do what the search query parameter `exact=0` already does by default. But I don't think you can set search terms like this as they are extracted directly from the search query `$q['s']` when the search SQL is generated in `WP_Query::parse_search()`. So it seems the search terms set here would be overridden and have no affect on the search SQL query. Cheers